# Throw an Exception if site exists before I create it

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm trying to execute the following code snippet which creates a new site from a webpart depending on the user input:

```
SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
SPWebCollection subSites = mySite.Webs;
string currentTemplate = mySite.WebTemplate;

string siteUrl = siteURL1;
string siteTitle = siteTitle1;
string siteDescription = siteDescription1;

subSites.Add(siteUrl, siteTitle, siteDescription, 1033,
currentTemplate, true, false);
```

How can I make an exception where the program will ignore the snippet if the site already exists? for example

```
   if (siteURL exists)
      code here;
   else
      do nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check `subSites.Names.Contains(siteUrl)`, which contains the names of all subsites. Check out the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412285.aspx) for details.